# Magento 2.3.3 Transactional Emails issue with the logo link

Tags: magento2.3, transactional-mail

I have uploaded the  Transactional Emails Logo image using the 
**Content->Design->Configuration** uploaded successfully but in the email does not show the proper link with the
link Of logo : 
https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/vWy5v75cdKbYCpO-9euWaV0tWWYYC1vkoy2y-NQb0DMLEfX041cTg0_HrrAjzH97tCY_Y3Z8_9_FhsEC6e1ENWi_n3BMHHOkgWVUXlbKYCMeNyGwiX3lw03hrw3vEB_090CnXU8=s0-d-e1-ft#http://test.site.co.uk/pub/media/email/logo/stores/1/logo.png

**How to remove the google user proxy link from the logo URL.
I need just http://test.site.co.uk/pub/media/email/logo/stores/1/logo.png**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clear and flush after placing new after check ?

Comment: Yes I have flush the catch.

Comment: are you check store wise ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is found only on localhost.
When you go to live the email logo show successful.